# Are people rational?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Does it say anywhere in the Sources that people are not rational?  By that I mean: A certain course of action may be the most logical and common-sensical from all angles, and people do something else.  Illogical heart over logical mind.

Now, I am not talking about believing things that are not part of our everyday experience.  Logic and reason are only the *road* that leads from assumed and unproven premises to conclusions.  For observant Jews, the Torah is the unquestioned premise, and rabbis use logic and reason to extract proper behavior from it -- so that's not where I am going.

So: Do you recall a general statement by a Sage saying people are not rational?

Comment: How about "I created the yetzer harah and the Torah as its antidote"?

Comment: The statement: "people are not rational" seems to be too extreme. Actually, people are rational. We have brains and thought processes, that are higher than mere instinct of the animal world. That people are capable of being irrational (despite our higher human abilities) is also obvious. Are you really looking for an absolute statement that people always choose to be irrational; or that we never appeal to our reason if we can appeal to our gut or emotions etc.?

Comment: Rav Yisrael Salanter has a lot to say about der dunkl (I guess we'd call it the unconscious or subconscious or something else I'm not enough of a psychologist to use correctly). And about negios, desires and biases we don't even realize are coloring our decisions. In his worldview, we FAR more often employ reason to justify our desires than base our desires on reason.

Comment: You are probably talking about Cognitive biases. Notice that "logical and common-sensical" are two contradicting things. People always do what's *common-sensical* for them but that common sense goes against *logic*. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Resh Lakish in [Sotah 3a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.3a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)  teaches us that *a person does not sin unless a* Ruach Shtus *enters them*.

A Ruach Shtus means an *air* of stupidity - in other words, that they begin to behave irrationally.

From [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.3a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) with minor edits:

> ריש לקיש אמר אין אדם עובר עבירה אלא אם כן נכנס בו רוח שטות שנאמר (במדבר ה, יב) איש איש כי תשטה אשתו תשטה כתיב‏
>
> Reish Lakish says: A man commits a transgression only if a spirit of folly [shetut] enters him, as it is stated: “If any man’s wife goes astray [tisteh]” (Numbers 5:12). The word tisteh is written with the Hebrew letter shin, affording an alternative reading of tishteh, which is related to the term for folly, the word shetut.

Comment: @Danny, you are assuming that the propensity to sin is irrational.  Sometimes it is, and sometimes it only reflects weak faith. Besides, you can make irrational choices without any of your options being a sin.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi - you asked _So: Do you recall a general statement by a Sage saying people are not rational?_ and I answered _Yes, I do - here is the statement._ :-)

Comment: Sorry.  RESH LAKISH assumes that the propensity to sin is irrational. Sometimes it is, and sometimes it only reflects weak faith. Besides, you can make irrational choices without any of your options being a sin.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I'm not sure what your comments are getting at. Reish Lakish isn't assuming anything; he's asserting, based on a Scriptural hint and presumably Tradition, that sin is the result of "רוח שטות," which sounds a great deal like "irrationality." Isn't that an example of exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: He said sin is irrational.  But that's only true for someone with perfect faith.  If doubt creeps in, sin is not necessarily irrational.  And irrationality frequently has nothing to do with sin.

Comment: Akrasia, the question of why people choose the wrong thing, even while knowing it's a bad choice, is a HUGE topic in philosophy. Don't try to tackle it in a comment chain.

Comment: -1 I fail to understand how sinning is connected to Cognitive biases?

Comment: @AlBerko - LOL! *You* are the one who introduced _Cognitive biases_ into this and now you're complaining that we don't refer to it.

Comment: Still not following. How rational is keeping Mitzvos?

Comment: @AlBerko - it's clear (to me) from his question that he's not discussing that angle - and I refuse to get into that. We keep the Mitzvoth because The Big Boss tells us to. It's perfectly rational to listen to a Higher Authority Who Knows Better Than Me. (It's irrational to think you know better than The Big Boss.)

Answer (score 1):

Some quotes from Mesilas Yesharim
Beginning of Chapter 2:
כי אחרי שיש לאדם דעה והשכל להציל את עצמו ולברוח מאבדון נשמתו
That is one power of our שכל. 
Also look at Chapter 9 "כי הנה האדון ברוך הוא עשה את האדם בעל שכל נכון וסברא נכוחה לשינהג עצמו על דרך טוב וישמר מן הדברים המזיקים אשר נבראו לענוש את הרשעים" although admittedly this is taken out of context.

However in Chapter 11 "שהעבירה מטמטמת לבו של אדם, כי מסלקת ממנו הדיעה האמיתית ורוח השכל שהקדוש ברוך הוא נותן לחסידים, כמו שאמר הכתוב (משלי ב): כי ה' יתן חכמה, והנה הוא נשאר בהמיי וחומרי משוקע בגסות העולם הזה.
" Here we see that our sechel that leads us to Chochma is something that can come externally to us from HaShem. 
More quotes from Chapter 11 about someone whose middos cause his שכל to fail וימצאו גאים אחרים שתשאר גאותם קבורה בלבם, לא יוציאוה אל המעשה, אבל יחשבו בלבבם שכבר הם חכמים גדולים יודעי הדברים לאמיתם ושלא רבים יחכמו כמוהם, על כן לא ישיתו לב אל דברי זולתם בחשבם כי מה שקשה עליהם לא יהיה נקל לאחרים, ומה ששכלם מראה להם כל כך ברור הוא וכל כך פשוט עד שלא יחושו לדברי החולקים עליהם אם ראשונים ואם אחרונים וספק אין אצלם על סברתם.
"

"והנה איש כזה כדאי להחריב עולם מלא אם יהיה יכולת בידו, כי אין השכל שולט בו כלל והוא סר טעם ממש ככל החיות הטורפות ועליו נאמר (איוב יח): טורף נפשו באפו הלמענך תעזב ארץ? והוא קל ודאי לעבור על מיני עבירות שבעולם אם חמתו תביאהו להם, כי כבר אין לו מניע אחר אלא כעסו ואל אשר יביאהו ילך.
"
From Chapter 21 "הנה הטרדות מכריחות את השכל ומערבבות אותו, ואינם מניחות אותו להתחזק ביראה ובאהבה, "

And look at this quote from Chapter 22. This is a significant one in answering the question "כי היותר חכם גדול שבינינו אינו כי אם מן תלמידי התלמידים אשר בדורות הראשונים. וזה מה שראוי שנבין ונדע באמת, ולא יזוח עלינו לבנו חנם, אלא נכיר שדעתנו קלה ושכלנו חלש עד מאד, הסכלות רב בנו והטעות גוברת, ואשר נדע אותו אינו אלא מעט מן המעט, אם כן ודאי שאין ראוי לנו ההנשא כלל אלא הבושת והשפלות וזה פשוט."

It keeps on getting more clear "ועל הכל יתבונן תמיד להכיר חולשת השכל האנושי, ורוב טעותיו וכזביו, שיותר קרוב לו תמיד הטעות מהידיעה האמתית."

On the power of the שכל from Chapter 25 "ואמנם הדבר הזה אינו מצטייר היטב בשכל האדם, אלא על ידי התמדת ההתבוננות וההסתכלות הגדול, כי כיון שהדבר רחוק מחושינו לא יציירוה השכל אלא אחר רוב העיון וההשקפה, וגם אחר שיציירהו יסור הציור ממנו בנקל אם לא יתמיד עליו הרבה" and "וכשיחשוב עוד וידמה בלבו רגע הכנסו לפני הבית דין הגדול של צבא מעלה, בעת שיראה עצמו לפני מלך מלכי המלכים הקב"ה הקדוש והטהור בתכלית הקדושה והטהרה בסוד קדושים משרתי גבורה גבורי כח עושי דברו אשר אין בהם כל מום, והוא עומד לפניהם גרוע פחות ונבזה מצד עצמו, טמא ומגואל מצד מעשיו הירים ראש? היהיה לו פתחון פה? וכי ישאלוהו איה איפוא פיך, איה גאונך וכבודך אשר נשאת בעולמך.
מה יענה או מה ישיב על תוכחתו, הנה ודאי שלו רגע אחד יצייר האדם בשכלו האמת הזה ציור אמתי וחזק, פרוח תפרח ממנו כל הגאוה ולא תשוב אליו עוד.
"

From all these questions I humbly think the answer based on the writings of the Ramchal is that our "חלק הנכבד שלו, דהיינו השכל" (Chapter 22) is *extremely* prone to mistakes. However it can be used to keep us clear of danger, physical or ruchni. Also, our שכל can be improved upon with purity of heart.

Comment: I can't understand this answer at all. This is an English language site, and as such all answers need to at least contain minimally understandable English content/summaries.

Comment: Im yirtzeh HaShem I'll translate and be marchiv tomorrow or soon thereafter, bli neder.

Comment: @Meuchedet would be great, you might find it easier to copy/paste the translation from Sefaria [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Messilat_Yesharim.2?lang=bi) after checking that you agree with it. A good way is to locate the chapter, search for some words of the Hebrew text, then locate the English

Comment: I'm more or less away from a computer until next week or week and a half. So it might take some time but I'll try not to forget to make my edits.